# Zookeeper for Apache-Kafka: problems with port 2181 in Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server

Tags: apache-kafka, port, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to figure out how to successfully reach the end of this tutorial, for the installation and first running of Apache-Kafka : [How To Install Apache Kafka on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://idroot.net/linux/install-apache-kafka-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

After killing the previously running zookeeper instance, I tried, again!, to start the zookeeper server again, but when the process reaches the phase of port binding, it stops forever..: [KafkaActivationFailed](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFa-5PfLdbSbX71V4hoii3qT9Bo4dD_4)

```
marco@PC:/usr/share/zookeeper$ sudo lsof -i :2181
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4545 zookeeper   32u  IPv6  43042      0t0  TCP *:2181 (LISTEN)
marco@PC:/usr/share/zookeeper$ sudo kill 4545


marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh   
config/zookeeper.properties
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,608] INFO Reading configuration from:  
config/zookeeper.properties  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,609] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,609] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,609] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,610] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in  
config, running  in standalone mode    
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,620] INFO Reading configuration from:  
config/zookeeper.properties   
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,620] INFO Starting server       
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,624] INFO Server  
environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03 
built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,624] INFO Server environment:host.name=PC.station  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_181 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle 
Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm
/java-8-oracle/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-
0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/usr/local/kafka
/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-
basic-auth-extension-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-
file-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/connect-transforms-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-
20.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/kafka
/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-
utils-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-
2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-
jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-
jaxb-annotations-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-
CR2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/.. 
/libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-
api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-
client-2.27.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.27.jar:
/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.27.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar:/usr/local/kafka
/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.27.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-
jaxb-2.27.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.27.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/jetty-http-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-
io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-
util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:
/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/kafka_2.11-2.0.0-sources.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-
clients-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-
2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.11-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-
streams-test-utils-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-
2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/kafka
/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-
3.5.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-
0.9.11.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka
/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-
logging_2.11-3.9.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-
2.11.12.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/..
/libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-
api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/local
/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/usr
/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib   
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:os.name=Linux  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:os.version=4.15.0-33-
generic (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:user.name=marco 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:user.home=/home/marco 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,625] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/usr/local/kafka 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,630] INFO tickTime set to 3000 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,630] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,630] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,634] INFO Using  
org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn Factory as server connection  
factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2018-09-04 12:18:14,636] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181   
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

The problem is that rebooting zookeeper seems active:

```
marco@PC:~$ netstat -ant | grep :2181
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                      
LISTEN
marco@PC:~$ systemctl status zookeeper
● zookeeper.service - LSB: centralized coordination service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/zookeeper; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-09-04 15:51:24 CEST; 2min 19s
   ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1919 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/zookeeper start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 25 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/zookeeper.service
           └─1997 /usr/bin/java -cp /etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share
/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share   
/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share
/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr

Sep 04 15:51:24 PC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: centralized coordination 
service...
Sep 04 15:51:24 PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: centralized coordination 
service.
```

But when trying to run kafka... :

```
marco@PC:~$ cd /usr/local/kafka
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh   
config/zookeeper.properties
[2018-09-04 15:54:29,981] INFO Reading configuration from:  
config/zookeeper.properties  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-09-04 15:54:29,982] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2018-09-04 15:54:29,983] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
...
[2018-09-04 15:54:30,012] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181  
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2018-09-04 15:54:30,013] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at 

sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
```

Comment: What is the problem? and what do you mean by "zookeeper remains idle"? Do you mean that no further logs are written to the log file?

Comment: Hi @GiorgosMyrianthous. The problem is that after rebooting, when trying to start kafka server it says: ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: You need to include this error in your question then. How did you kill zookeeper process?

Comment: But when I do marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ systemctl status zookeeper it seems active:
● zookeeper.service - LSB: centralized coordination service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/zookeeper; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-09-04 15:51:24 CEST; 1h 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1919 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/zookeeper start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 04 15:51:24 PC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: centralized coordination service...
Sep 04 15:51:24 PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: centralized coordination service.
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$

Comment: then before killing the process run systemctl stop zookeeper. after killing the id(might not be needed), run systemctl start zookeeper

Comment: Now it seems that there is no active zookeeper: marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ sudo systemctl stop zookeeper
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ sudo lsof -i :2181
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$

Comment: After stopping zookeeper, I tried again to run kafka with marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties   but the activation of kafka stops again at this line: [2018-09-04 17:11:24,572] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

Comment: This is what I mean for stopping of the kafka server start/activation https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFa-5PfLdbSbX71V4hoii3qT9Bo4dD_4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  config/zookeeper.properties
```

This started okay if you look at the logs

> [2018-09-04 12:18:14,636] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

And this message will sit there until a Zookeeper client such as Kafka connects to Zookeeper.

When you say you're "trying to run kafka", you're running `zookeeper-server-start` again, not `kafka-server-start`, so Zookeeper is already bound to port 2181 and it won't start a second one.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 . After removing zookeeper and kafka, I re-installed them. Then I followed the steps indicated here:   https://idroot.net/linux/install-apache-kafka-ubuntu-18-04-lts/   . In Step 4 Start Kafka Server: cd /usr/local/kafka   bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties. It actually says "[2018-09-05 08:43:16,719] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)" but, as you can see from here:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bKtnn6hoyh9jdel5ToCEzUmQ0AQ5_vBT  the activation phase stops just there.

Comment: There is no error there, and that output is expected.... Zookeeper is now running and waiting for connections, not "stuck". You need to open a **new** terminal and start Kafka

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I "solved" the problem:

I left opened the "idle" window ( [First Window](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1bKtnn6hoyh9jdel5ToCEzUmQ0AQ5_vBT) ), I opened a new window and started the kafka server : Step 2.b of [ApachaKafka-QuickStart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) : /usr/local/ kafka/ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties  ( [Second Window](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qtH05zS_B6KozTRJbM4AHbamcdaTAzKI) ). Then I opened another window to create a topic and send some messages:

```
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181   
--replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
Created topic "test".
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
test
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092   
--topic test
>This is a message
>This is another message
>
```

( [ThirdWindow](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BU8wThrejE93YTdNy8DJoqyoOwVYWC2f) ) . Finally, in another new window I started a consumer :

```
marco@PC:/usr/local/kafka$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server  
localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
This is a message
This is another message
```

: ( [FourthWindow](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1otFTE28uNAgP7q1DZF4h1jp_KtVmhjIa) )

What I actually do not understand now is why I should open all these four sessions.

Marco

Comment: You only need minimum of three terminals. Two to start the services in the foreground. One to create topics and send data. And after you send data, you can consume it

Comment: Thanks a lot @cricket_007

Comment: Welcome! Also, Confluent Platform includes Deb/yum packages with systemctl scripts, which make service management easier (Confluent is not a custom version of Kafka)